# what is this delimeter (^) in PHP regular expression functions

Tags: php, regex

I am used to the delimiter of `/..../` in regular expressions, and I am used to the symbol `^` being used to indicate the beginning of a string, or the negation when used on a class of characters.  So when I came across the line below using `^....^`, I was puzzled:

```
$t = "172,249,L,P";
preg_split("^,^", $t);
```

What does this mean if anything?

Answer (score 4):

You can use several various delimiters for the purposes of not having them be escaped in your particular regexp string:

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Yes as stated in the documentation. `A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
preg_split("^,^", $t);
```

is the same as this code:

```
preg_split("/,/", $t);
```

The use of `^` as a delimiter for the regular expression, and `^` as a metacharacter within the regular expression, are unrelated.

Comment: you can have all three: `preg_split("^\^[\^0-9]^", $t);`